# How to hide element if it contain specific div with a class

Tags: html, css

I have this html structure:

```
<div>
<div class="parent">
<div>
  <div class="label">
    <div class="xyz"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
<div>
  <div class="label">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to hide the parent if it is contains div with `class="xyz"`
I tried that:

```
.parent div.xyz {
  display: none;
}
```

but seems like my selector does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In css, there's no parent element selector. In your case, you can use jquery to achieve the solution.

```
$('.parent:has(.xyz)').addClass('hide');

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.xyz .parent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="xyz">
    <div class="parent">
      <div>
        <div class="label">
          <div class="xyz"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div class="label">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can not select an ancestor, just descendants, an example of how you could do is like this:

```
<div class="xyz">
<div class="parent">
  <div class="label">
    <div class="xyz"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="label">
  </div>
</div>
</div>

div.xyz .parent {
  display: none;
}
```

in this case you will hide both `.parent` class

[See more about descending selector](http://descending%20select%20https://www.sitepoint.com/descendant-selector-css-selector/)

to select a parent or element inside another wapper you will need to use javascript

Comment: seems like does not work

Comment: I correct, was wrog `display: hidden;` the correct is `display: none;`

Comment: seems like the selector does not work

Comment: seems like I got one more div level. just edited the question

Comment: do you want hide only the first `.parent`?

Comment: nope, any parent that has the `xyz` in its child `div div.xyz`

Comment: I can not alter the html to add more classes that is the problem

Comment: as stated, without javascript you can only do the inverse path, I put the target class encapsulated by the xyz class, if this is not useful you will have to use javascript
tried to follow a line without javascript is already described this intention in the post
I updated my answer

Comment: can you add a js code?

Comment: nope I can not add js code

Comment: do you think this one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has can help?

Comment: exists the `:has` selector to do this that you want, but none browse suports yet :c
you this is the only way, we can't help you, sorry

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahas here the suports of `:has`

Answer (score 0):

You can Hide the parent element with the following jquery

```
jQuery('.parent').each(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).find('div.xyz').length != 0) {
        jQuery(this).closest('.parent').hide();
    }
});
```

Hope it will helpful.